# Как запретить скрывать клавиатуру при скрроле списка ReactNative

Tags: listview, клавиатура, react-native

У меня есть список (ListView) и в каждой ячейке есть .
Если нажать на TextInput который внизу экрана, то список пролистывается так что б элемент был над клавиатурой и открывается клавиатура, после чего сразу же закрывается (проблема первая), если же поставить курсор на самый последний элемент списка то после закрытия клавиатуры список еще и пролистывается обратно и получаеться что в него ввести данные вообще не возможно.
Помогите пожалуйста, зарание спасибо

Код:

```
renderCell(rowData, rowID) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.measurement}>
                <Image style={styles.image}
                       source={{uri: rowData.picture}}/>
                <View style={{margin: 10}}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.getName(rowData)}</Text>
                    <TextInput style={{marginTop: 4, height: 40, borderWidth: 1, fontSize: 14, alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}
                               keyboardType='numeric'
                               maxLength={6}
                               numberOfLines={1}
                               placeholder="value in centimeters"
                               value={this.getValue(this.state.sizes, rowID)}
                               onChangeText={(text) => {
                                   this.state.values[rowID] = {
                                       name_ru: rowData.name_ru,
                                       name_en: rowData.name_en,
                                       value: text
                                   }
                               }}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

P.S. пробывал использовать react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view - без результатно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение заключалось в следующем:

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    <FlatList
        data={dataSource}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderCell(item, index)}/>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Вместо ListView